# Bash script release prompt after Lamba update

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

AWS Lambda bash deploy script:

```
01 #!/usr/bin/env bash
02 cp package.json ./dist
03 cp -a ./env/ ./dist/env
04 cd ./dist
05 npm install --silent --only=prod
06 zip -q -r ../function.zip .
07 cd ../
08 aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --zip-file fileb://function.zip
09 rm ./function.zip
```

The above script works fine, however, the prompt is not released after L08 `aws lambda update-function-code` step, instead, I see the output from AWS CLI in a text file and the prompt just hangs (must press `Q` to quit).

```
{
    "FunctionName": "foo",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:xxx:xxxx:function:xxx",
    "Runtime": "nodejs14.x",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxxxxxxx",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "CodeSize": 24471144,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "LastModified": "2022-01-27T23:38:54.000+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "frtAS71k17XuXNB1xQUTyaBsTcE/8aBUWoBgpGrfFYA=",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "61ea91d6-9e85-4aa1-93e1-0784c359f5b4",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "InProgress",
    "LastUpdateStatusReason": "The function is being created.",
    "LastUpdateStatusReasonCode": "Creating",
    "Architectures": [
        "x86_64"
    ]
}
```

It seems the script gets stuck inside VIM? How do I get out and proceed to the next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue seems to be caused by the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a **pager**. You can turn off the pager by appending this to your `aws` command: `--no-paginate`

Alternatively, put these lines in the `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

For more information, see: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Comment: Brilliant! Adding `--no-cli-pager` did the trick e.g:

`aws lambda update-function-code --no-cli-pager --function-name myLambdaFunction --zip-file fileb://function.zip`